# Derivative in the tangent space of a metric manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, smooth-manifolds, inner-products

Consider a differentiable finite dimensional manifold $M$ with $\text{dim}M = n$,
modelled on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a metric tensor $g$, at any point $p \in M$, the tangent space $T_pM$ can be equipped with a norm $||v|| = \sqrt{g_p(v,v)}$. Thus, a curve
$\gamma:\mathbb{R} \to T_pM$ can be differentiated (assuming the derivative exists) :

$$ \lim_{|h|\to 0} \frac{||\gamma(x+h)-\gamma(x)- Ah ||_{T_pM}}{|h|} = 0, $$ where $A: \mathbb{R} \to T_pM$.

Why I have never seen something like this ? Instead, the everyone uses the definition

$$ \gamma'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\gamma(x+h)-\gamma(x)}{h}, $$ independently of the existence of a metric. Why ?

Comment: I don't get your definition of the derivative. How are you choosing $w$? Why would you take the norm of the difference? The derivative should be a vector, not a scalar...

Comment: @DonThousand Yeah you are right corrected it. The definition I am using is that of the Frechet derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative

Comment: You have not corrected it correctly. The derivative is $A$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Better ?

Comment: your second definition is wrong, it must be just $h$ instead of $|h|$ in the two place it is

Comment: It's a rather confusing question. The manifold has nothing to do with this problem. There's just a single finite-dimensional vector space $T_p M$ (possibly with an inner product) and a curve $\gamma$ this space.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Yes I know, the thing is I thought that this derivative had something to do with the affine connection, but it has not.

Answer (score 1):

The second definition is not independent of a distance function, as a limit in a metric space is defined using a distance function (in this case a norm), that is, the expression $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)=L$ for some function $f:A\to B$ is equivalent to

$$
\forall \epsilon >0,\,\exists \delta >0:0<d_A(x,y)<\delta\implies  d_B(f(y),L)<\epsilon 
$$

where $d_A$ and $d_B$ are the distances in $A$ and $B$ respectively. In your case the expression $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\gamma (x+h)-\gamma (x)}{h}=\gamma '(x)$ is equivalent to

$$
\forall \epsilon >0,\, \exists \delta >0:0<|h|<\delta \implies \left\|  \frac{\gamma (x+h)-\gamma (x)}{h}-\gamma '(x)\right\|_{T_pM}<\epsilon 
$$

what is exactly the same definition of the Fréchet derivative when $h$ is real.

Comment: Does the derivative remains the same independently of my choice of a (metric induced ) norm  ?

Comment: Originally what I had in mind was that one can derive without any metric given, if an affine connection is provided, but now I understand (if I  am correct) the thing is the affine connection is not related with this derivative at all it is only connected with another kind of derivative, the one that takes place as one travels from one point (and tangent space) to another. So this derivation is metric dependent and can not happen unless I provide a metric tensor on $M$. Am I correct ?

Comment: @kot all norms are equivalent in a finite dimensional space, so yes, the derivative is independent of the chosen norm. Nothing in your question is related to something specific to differential geometry, an affine connection is a very different thing as the derivation happens in the manifold, not on some specific tangent space